# Cannot start Java ME Device Selector

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, java-me

I just installed Java ME SDK version 8.3 to create Java projects for my Raspberry pi.
After starting the device selector manually, it stops after round about 5 seconds. I have the newest JDK version and also tried a few different ME SDK versions. Anyone who can help out?

Comment: Same problem for Ubuntu 17.04,
works fine on Ubuntu 15.10,
I don't get this...

Answer (score 2):

In Java version “1.8.0_121”, there is a new “Implement Serialization Filtering” See : JDK-8155760.

A solution for this problem is:

1) Edit C:\Program Files\Java_ME_platform_SDK_8.3\bin\java.properties

2) Set the path to your JDK installation directory (supposing: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131")

3) Go to your JDK installation directory:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\security\java.security and add this setting:

```
jdk.serialFilter=*

sun.rmi.registry.registryFilter=*

sun.rmi.transport.dgcFilter=\

java.rmi.server.ObjID;\

java.rmi.server.UID;\

java.rmi.dgc.VMID;\

java.rmi.dgc.Lease;\

maxdepth=5;maxarray=10000
```